# How to pass ng-model as parameter to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

How can i pass the ng-model with it's value as a parameter to a function in a controller from html.I tried to pass the ng-model as string to the controller but it didn;t works can anyone tell me how to do it.

Html:

```
<input stopccp decimalpoint
      ng-model="vm.product.rate"
      placeholder="0"
      type="number"
      ng-change="vm.fillStarted()"
      maxlength="5"
      ng-keydown="vm.checkMaxLength(5, vm.product.rate)"
      ng-click= "vm.hideScrollContent()"/>
```

Controller:

```
var vm = this;
function checkMaxLength (maxLength, model) {
  $log.log('checkMaxLength got called', maxLength);
  $log.log('model is', model);
  $log.log('model value', model.value);
  // if (vm.product.rate.length === maxLength) {
  //   vm.product.rate.value = vm.product.rate.value.slice(0, -1);
  // }
}
```

Logs:

```
checkMaxLength got called 5
model is 
model value undefined
```

Comment: try $scope.vm.product.rate

Comment: @zb22 do i have to do it in html

Comment: @zb22 `vm` is most likely a scope from _controller as_ syntax

Comment: are u able to call the checkMaxLength method.

Comment: @Ved yes i could able to call the checkMaxLength method

Comment: @What is the result you are getting now in your log?

Comment: paste out of `$log.log('model is', model);` Also ` $log.log('model value', model.value);` is wrong.

Comment: @Nidhinkumar what is vm?

Comment: @zb22 can you check the updated question pls

Comment: You dont need to pass it. you can access it directly in your function using $scope

Comment: @zb22 [_here is a tutorial on how `vm` is used_](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected. As you are calling method on `ng-keydown` first time you will not see any value. For second input you should see the first input value

```
<input stopccp decimalpoint
      ng-model="vm.product.rate"
      placeholder="0"
      type="number"
      ng-change="vm.fillStarted()"
      maxlength="5"
      ng-keydown="vm.checkMaxLength(5, vm.product.rate)"
      ng-click= "vm.hideScrollContent()"/>


function checkMaxLength (maxLength, model) {
  $log.log('checkMaxLength got called', maxLength);
  $log.log('model is', model);//enter 123 in input. You should see 12 here
  $log.log('model value', model.value);// It is wrong as model.value will always 
    be undefined

}
```

> Use ng-keyup instead you ng-keydown to see typed input in log.

Comment: what do you mean by model name?

Comment: vm.product.rate

Comment: instead of model  value you need `ng-model` expression?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks totally fine, i guess the issue lies here

var vm = this;

and then you need to assign value to the product , otherwise it will be undefined.

```
this.product = {};
var vm = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access it simply within the `controller`.

So change your `ng-keydown` into:

```
ng-keydown="vm.checkMaxLength(5)"
```

And then inside your `checkMaxLength` function simply use:

```
function checkMaxLength (maxLength) {
  $log.log('checkMaxLength got called', maxLength);
  $log.log('model is', vm.product.rate);
}
```

And of course inside the controller you should have your product object init:

```
vm.product = {};
```

in order to use its `rate` property as model